# Laravel 5.3, MySQL, proper foreign key setup in migrations (one to many, many to many)

Tags: mysql, laravel-5.3, laravel-migrations

what is the proper way to setup the foreign key restrains in following scentarios.

Let say I have models `Post`, `User`, `Tag`.

At the moment my migrations are all set simply as:

For `Comment` model:

```
$table->integer('posts_id')->unsigned(); //comment must belong to a post
$table->integer('user_id')->nullable()->unsigned(); //comment can belong to an user
$table->integer('something_id')->unsigned(); // each Something model will have at most 5 to 10 comments in it - this is what is called cardinality if I got it right so the average cardinality is 7.5
```

and let's say for a many to many relation I have a pivot table between `Posts` and `Tags` as:

```
$table->integer('post_id')->unsigned(); //connecting the post
$table->integer('tag_id')->unsigned(); //connecting the tag
```

Now I need to index the fields so when my db queries are executed they're executed as fast as possible.

What I would do now is create new migration as:

```
$table->foreign('posts_id')->references('id')->on('posts');
$table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users'); 
$table->foreign('something_id')->references('id')->on('somethings');
```

And the same for the pivot table:

```
$table->foreign('post_id')->references('id')->on('posts');
$table->foreign('tag_id')->references('id')->on('tags');
```

My questions are:

- Is this the proper way to do this, if not how should I do it instead?
- Is there some restrictions, downsides or anything I should be aware of here?
- Would I gain anything by doing `$table->foreign('something_id')->references('id')->on('somethings');` as the cardinality here is about 7.5? Updating of `comments.something_id` will never happen in my app, and the ratio of "creation of new `something` row" to "reading related `something` row from `comment` row" would be really low 1:10^5 (rough estimate and in next row of optimizations I'll work on caching the queries so not sure how relevant this information is)

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to create new migration file for defining foreign key.

```
$table->foreign('posts_id')->references('id')->on('posts');
$table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users'); 
$table->foreign('something_id')->references('id')->on('somethings');
```

put those inside comment table migration file. And

```
$table->foreign('post_id')->references('id')->on('posts');
$table->foreign('tag_id')->references('id')->on('tags');
```

in pivot table migration file.